# Can Protractor tests be run in a mobile device and How?

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, protractor

I have seen that Protractor tests can be run with a [Mobile Setup as described in Protractor Documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/mobile-setup), but this means you are running the tests on emulators. What I would like to accomplish is having the Protractor tests running in real mobile devices.

I cannot find any clue if this is possible and how can I do it. I am currently testing a website, so I use Protractor for automate an smoke and regression test. It would be very useful if I can use the same tests over different browsers and physical mobile devices that we already have on our company to test manually.

Does anybody use Protractor in that way?

Comment: So tell us what you ended up with?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into running your tests on browserstack, or another site with similar capabilities.   https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities

Here is some info to get you up and running: http://www.blog.wishtack.com/single-post/2015/05/07/Cross-Browser-Testing-test-automation-with-Protractor-and-Browserstack.

Hope this helps.